# Automation testing on mobile web using Chrome on Android and ios.

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I'm currently doing an automation testing on mobile web. I inspect the element on chrome desktop and run it on Chrome using Android, it works fine. But the issue is when I run the test script on Chrome using ios it failed. 
Can anyone help me? Can I run the test script using Chrome on ios?  Do I need to create separate scripts for Android and ios?

Comment: did u tried debugging on safari browser for iOS ?

Comment: I try it. But now i need to use the same script for both ios and android then run it on Chrome. I did a research on how to run Chrome on ios but didnt get any info that I need.

Comment: Is it a Hybrid app? Did you try checking element locator of the same element on both iOS and Android? Try making use of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179396/is-there-any-way-to-debug-chrome-in-any-ios-device) for debugging.