# How to get console logs on Chrome mobile without usb debug?

Tags: google-chrome, web, console.log, chrome-debugging

I once came across an SO answer that gave a Chrome URL to navigate to, that had a button to "enable" JS console logging. After enabling the logging, that tab would show the console logs of other Chrome tabs.

I know this answer seems like a duplicate, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding how to do that again. It was super convenient since it gave the console logs on any Chrome browser without needing a USB connected.

Any ideas? I know I came across it in an SO question about iOS debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it! So, it's actually a Chrome on iOS only feature.

URL: chrome://inspect

That URL won't show anything on Chrome for Android, which tripped me up. But, on iOS it shows a "Start Logging" button.

[image]

Answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55433616/2096769

Comment: I'm using it on iOS. Working pretty fine

Comment: Any way to make it show for android?

Comment: @FiddleFreak not to my knowledge, seems like they only added it to iOS. On Android connecting your phone to a laptop and then opening chrome://inspect on the laptop works pretty well though. I think iOS was given the ability to show logging because Chrome on iOS is just Safari reskinned, debug capabilities are limited on iOS.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I just found in android studio, if you do ctrl+m and tap "open debugger", then chrome will open the following url `http://localhost:expoPort/debugger-ui/`, and you can see what is happening in the console.