# Button submits perfectly in desktop browsers but won't submit in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a login button in a React component that works perfectly in desktop browsers but not on mobile. I'm finding it hard to debug.

This is the form.

```
 <form className="signin_form" onSubmit={onLogin}>
          <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="email"></label>
          <input
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEmail(e.target.value);
            }}
            className="form_input"
            type="text"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            autoFocus
          />

          <label className="sr-only" htmlFor="password"></label>
          <input
            onChange={(e) => {
              setPassword(e.target.value);
            }}
            className="form_input"
            type="password"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
          />
          {error && (
            <p className="error error_message">
              Username or password is incorrect
            </p>
          )}
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn_primary">
            Sign In
          </button>
        </form>
```

And here is the function that is called on submit

```
const onLogin = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const result = await axios.post(`${url}/login`, {
        email,
        password,
      });

      dispatch({ type: SET_TOKEN, payload: result.data.token });

      if (result.data.status === 1) {
        const newData = await axios.get(`${url}/syncStore`, {
          headers: { token: result.data.token },
        });

        dispatch({
          type: UPDATE_STORE,
          payload: newData.data,
        });

        navigate("/dashboard");
      } else {
        showError();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Any help greatly appreciated

The button call the backend api and check creds. Then log in the user. It just won't work on mobile.

I've tested on Safari, Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if some other div elements are overlapping the button in mobile device, if you are using responsive css. Sometimes problem was in styles of div elements.

Comment: I can't see anything overlapping the button and it works in responsive mode in chrome tools on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

### Code-related answer

In my opinion, the bug can be related to the submit callback being async. As such, it returns a `Promise` that may remain in its initial state without being ever fired thus, your code is never executed.

First thing you can do is wrap your code this way:

```js
const onLogin = (e) => {
  (async function() {
    // your code here
  })().catch(console.error)
}
```

### General debugging on Mobile

The bug you're experiencing may be related to how you're code is transpiled: if you're using ES2015+ features without polyfilling them, may be unsupported in some mobile browsers. If you're using [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/), [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/914) may help you, otherwise you can take a look at [Core JS](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Also, I'd suggest to check for unsupported features on [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/).

It may also be related to some race conditions which, by chance, you didn't ever see during development. To try spot them you can try throttling network speed and CPU ([Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/#throttle) as an example).

If the steps above didn't work, you can:

- simulate mobile with [Chrome's mobile view](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/);
- debug on physical device or using an emulator (links for convenience: [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio), [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)) either by:

  - debug directly on mobile using Chrome, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55433616/7432968);
  - use remote debbugging with a PC or Mac:

    - [Chrome for Android docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/);
    - outdated [Safari Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) which should still hold (didn't try myself).

Answer (score 0):

I had redeployed the frontend without changing a url variable so it was pointing to localhost on the server! School boy error!